# Spring Cloud Hystrix fails at first command call

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix

I noticed the first Hystrix command always calls my fallback, and after that the following calls works fine in Spring Cloud Netflix.

Is there any setting should I set to avoid it? Why does it happen?

Comment: The fallback is only called if there is an exception. I guess you need to share the code if you want to get any more insight than that.

Comment: The matter is the same method works fine in the second call, the issue is only for the first one. I read about a warm up, but I did not find any solution.

Comment: Add additional details (code, config, etc.) to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: Here is the scenario: the service is started, eureka server shows the service registered on dashboard, the UI client is started, when the hystrix method is called, the fallback method is triggered. At the second time where the hystrix method is called the feign client works fine and gets the response from remote service. Can you try this scenario and see what happens?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

looks like a side effect of an infrastructure initialization and as timeout on it https://groups.google.com/d/msg/hystrixoss/_jnxAyS20lA/fWo0ZAHoxt8J

Comment: Yes, I saw it... but in there it was not explain a solution for it. How can I fix it?

Comment: guess there isn't common solution for this issue :( https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/810. of course you can try set most timeout for "manual warm up" but not sure that that is good idea.

Comment: How can I set this manual warm up? Why is not a good idea? tks.

Comment: in theory you can try set bigger timeout for few first requests and set it to default value but it's a really bad idea cuz you are trying to solve issues in your IO on application lvl. what about just skipping few timeout errors on application startup or ignoring this first occurrence?

Comment: That sounds as a workaround to solve the first time exception, that's really awkward in hytrix. Why would someone project this behavior?

Comment: sorry, i have no idea why hystrix works in this way. guess they think that you should solve your IO related issues before doing anything on application lvl

Answer (score 0):

I addressed that by sending the failed request again from the *fallback* method, this time finding the IP of one of the remote pods with `DicoveryClient`:

```
private String getNameFallback(int delay) {
    RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
    return rt.getForObject(getUrl(delay), String.class);
}

private String getUrl(int delay) {
    String url = String.format("http://%s/name?delay=%d", SERVICE_ID, delay);
    if (discoveryClient != null) {
        Optional<ServiceInstance> svc = discoveryClient.getInstances(SERVICE_ID).stream().findFirst();
        if (svc.isPresent()) {
            String host = svc.get().getHost();
            int port = svc.get().getPort();
            url = "http://" + host + ":" + port + "?delay=" + delay;
        }
    }
    return url;
}
```

You can find more details [here](https://github.com/lubumbax/kubernetes-circuitbreaker-ribbon-example)